# How to compare two objects in arraylist and make it as one object

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a array list

```
`List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>()
Employee emp1 = new Employee()
emp1.setEmpNumber("1234");
emp1.setDueAmount("11");
emp1.setAge(20)
Employee emp2 = new Employee()
emp2.setEmpNumber("1234");
emp2.setDueAmount("14");
emp2.setAge(20)
Employee emp3 = new Employee()
emp3.setEmpNumber("567");
emp3.setDue("11");
emp3.setAge(20)
Employee emp4 = new Employee()
emp4.setEmpNumber("891");
emp4.setDueAmount("11");
emp4.setAge(20)
Employee emp5 = new Employee()
emp5.setEmpNumber("1234");
emp5.setDueAmount("14");
emp5.setAge(20)`
```

In the List there are three employee with the same Number but the due amount is different.
How to compare employee number by retrieving the list and add the due amount and make that object as single object?

Comment: You update one and remove the other. Repeat until done.

Comment: What does that company use for their database?

Answer (score 0):

Use SortedSet for ignoring

```
SortedSet<Employee > employee = new TreeSet<Employee >(new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee arg0, Employee arg1) {
        return arg0.getEmpNumber().compareTo(arg1.getEmpNumber());
    }
});

 if(employee.contains(emp1)){
   // iterate over employee find Employee  object with same number and add due in that object    
 }else{
     employee.add(emp1); // ..etc    
 }
```

And now if you insert a Employee into your employee , the duplicates (based on their emp number) will not be inserted.

IfAnd then you can iterate over employee find Employee  object with same number and add due in that object

Answer (score -1):

I would run through the list, use a map to store employees (with the employee number as key) and update the due ammounts on the fly.

Edit:
Not tested, but it should work as followed:

```
final Map<String, Employee> empMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>(); 

for (final Employee employee : list) {
  final String key = employee.getEmpNumber();
  if (empMap.containsKey(key)) {
    empMap.get(key).addDue(employee.getDue());
  } else {
    empMap.put(key, employee);
  }
}

list.clear(); 
list.addAll(empMap.values());
```

Comment: Now the size of the object is 5 after adding due amount i want to remove the remaining two objects in the list could you please place the code how to do it

Comment: Afterwards you would replace the content of the list with the content of the map (it provides methods to deliver only a set containing the values).

Comment: Code provided in my answer above.

Comment: @user3575404 Please update your post rather than posting long code in comments ;)

Comment: If my list is having more than 10000 records then it will be a performance issue right ?

Comment: Depends on how often you have to do this. Keep in mind that your "IDs" are Strings. Comparing Strings is very expensive (in other words: slow).